# Due Date set via EWS is wrong in reminder popup

Tags: c#, asp.net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I'm having some trouble using EWS with tasks and reminders, specifically, the due date.

When I run my code, shown below, the task is added to my exchange account and I can see it fine in outlook. All the data in it looks fine too. However, if I specify to have a reminder for the task, the due date it shows is very wrong.

It's usually 17 hours in the future, but the screenshot I've provided shows it being 19 hours in the future. I'm finding it very strange that if I open the task, the due date looks fine, but the reminder is saying it is due well into the future. Any ideas?

Screenshot: http://s970.photobucket.com/albums/ae187/paulehn/?action=view&current=ewstask.jpg

```
ExchangeVersion exchVersion = new ExchangeVersion();
exchVersion = ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1;
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(exchVersion);
service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
service.Url = new Uri("https://mail.domain.com.au/ews/exchange.asmx");

Task task = new Task(service);
task.Subject = "Subject";
task.Body = new MessageBody(BodyType.HTML, "Body");
task.StartDate = DateTime.Today;
task.DueDate = DateTime.Now.AddHours(2);
task.ReminderDueBy = DateTime.Now;
task.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 15;
task.IsReminderSet = true;
task.Save();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this is actually a 'feature' of Outlook, rather than a bug -

http://www.outlook-tips.net/archives/2009/20090623.htm

Answer (score 0):

You should probably make sure that all date and time are in the same timezone.
The best approach is to use UTC for everything.